# Por quê minha requisição AJAX não retorna o nome do meu arquivo de imagem?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Não sei como obter o retorno esperado do AJAX com a instrução event.preventDefault() habilitada. Sem esta função a requisição é executada e o navegador vai direto para a página do arquivo PHP onde obtenho os dados das variáveis corretamente, mas com ela habilitada parece que o arquivo PHP é percorrido sem que os dados do arquivo de imagem sejam atribuídos à global $_FILES (os dados do input_texto são retornados normalmente).

Html

```
<form id='myForm' name = 'myForm' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='myFile.php'>"
<input name='input_texto' type='text'>
<input name='image_input' type='file' id='file' accept='image/*'>
<input form='myForm' type='submit' value='Enviar'>
```

Script

```
 $("#myForm").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    var actionUrl = form.attr('action');

    $.ajax({
       url: actionUrl,
       data: form.serialize(),
       type: "POST",
       success: function(data) {
          alert(data);
       }
    });
 });
```

PHP

```
echo $_FILES['image_input']['name'];
echo $_POST['input_texto'];
```

Comment: "*sem que os dados do arquivo de imagem sejam atribuídos à global*", de fato isso acontece. Veja aqui dezenas de perguntas que tratam como fazer upload utilizando AJAX: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bajax%5D+upload

Comment: se precisa fazer uma chamada *ajax*, que é assíncrona por natureza, não deveria fazer no evento *submit*, faça a ação num botão comum que não faça submit, e após o retorno assíncrono do *ajax*, lá no `success`, ai faz o submit

Comment: @RicardoPontual mas a ideia do AJAX é justamente substituir a ação do submit. Qual seria a diferença em fazer em um botão "comum"?

Comment: A solução foi o uso de um objeto formData ao invés do form.serialize(). Obrigado a todos pelo auxílio.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

O problema pode estar relacionado ao uso do `serialize()` na chamada AJAX. A função `serialize()` serializa os dados do formulário em uma string de consulta que é enviada ao servidor.

Isso significa que apenas os dados dos campos de formulário que possuem o atributo `name` são enviados, mas não os dados do arquivo selecionado.

Para enviar dados de arquivo usando AJAX, você precisa usar um objeto `FormData` que permite a você enviar dados de arquivo e outros dados do formulário em uma única solicitação AJAX.

Para usar `FormData`, você precisa criar um novo objeto do tipo `FormData` e adicionar os dados do formulário a ele usando o método `append()`.

Em seguida, você pode enviar o objeto FormData usando o método `$.ajax()`.

Aqui está um exemplo de como usar `FormData` para enviar dados de arquivo usando AJAX:

```js
$("#myForm").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    var actionUrl = form.attr('action');

    var formData = new FormData(form[0]); // cria o objeto FormData a partir do formulário

    $.ajax({
       url: actionUrl,
       data: formData,
       type: "POST",
       contentType: false, // não definir o tipo de conteúdo
       processData: false, // não processar os dados
       success: function(data) {
          alert(data);
       }
    });
 });
```

Observe que os parâmetros `contentType` e `processData` são definidos como false. Isso é necessário para evitar que o jQuery tente processar o objeto `FormData`. Se esses parâmetros forem definidos como `true`, o jQuery tentará processar o objeto `FormData` como uma string, o que resultará em um erro.

Além disso, lembre-se de que o arquivo enviado deve ser tratado corretamente no servidor para que possa ser salvo ou processado corretamente. Você deve verificar se o arquivo foi enviado corretamente e se ele atende aos requisitos necessários antes de processá-lo.

Comment: Obrigado! O uso do formData funcionou perfeitamente.